# Complimentary PWM generation with timer IC

Tags: pwm, timer, counter

Provided PWM1, with frequency f and duty d, I need to generate PWM2 with frequency f and duty d but phase shifted 180 degree relative to PWM1.

Requirements:

- small foot print, the board space is very limited
- low component count, IC without external RC is preferred
- f > 20 kHz, d < 50%
- phase shift accuracy < 10 degree
- stay synchronized so PWM1 and PWM2 can never be both high

Comment: You need to provide more information. What is the input signal for your PWM? What are your requirements? How precise must the 180° phaseshift be?

Comment: Seems that what you need is an inside logic part of TL494 or similar IC. Circuit is shown in its datasheet.

Comment: @kruemi input signal: the first sentence of the question; requirements: the big list in the question; phase shift accuracy: added.

Answer (score 2):

> low component count, IC without external RC is preferred.

Then use the cheapest, lowest-pin-count MCU having a timer input/output. Program its input capture for incoming PWM, and timer output for PWM output.

Comment: that doesn't sound trivial, not every architecture support duty capture and complimentary PWM output. Can you provide an example ?

Comment: @7E10FC9A I'm not going to suggest you any product but, just as an example, you can take a look at Renesas RL78 series MCUs. Even 10-pin models have input capture and PWM output.